# Hibernate IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

thanks for any help you can provide. I'm absolutely stuck here.

I'm currently having trouble on webapp startup with what seems to be happening deep in the Hibernate code. This is while Spring context is initializing. I have been attempting to update the versions of the dependencies in this project from Spring 3.0.5 and Hibernate 3.6.10 to Spring 5.0.20 and Hibernate 5.2.18

Specifically, the error is happening here in org.hibernate.service.StandardServiceInitiators

`serviceInitiators.add( DialectResolverInitiator.INSTANCE );`
I am getting the IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing Class.

Here are the results of
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ncsts ---
[INFO] pinpoint:ncsts:war:CrossbowTest
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.3.1.Final)
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:9.2.1.jre8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.17)
[INFO] |  |  +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.14:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.13)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.19.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.10.4)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.4)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.19.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.20.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:5.0.20.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.jamonapi:jamon:jar:2.75:compile
[INFO] +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.1.2-b05:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:056:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_08:compile
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_08:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.facelets:jsf-facelets:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl:jar:3.3.3.Final.IE9patch:compile
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl-jsf2:jar:3.3.3.Final.IE9patch:compile
[INFO] +- org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-ui:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk:tomahawk:jar:1.1.6-patched:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.tomahawk:tomahawk-facelets:jar:1.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk:tomahawk-sandbox:jar:1.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.6)
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- au.com.bytecode:opencsv:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.wss:xws-security:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- jgroups:jgroups:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:oss-parent:pom:2:compile
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.ncsts.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.4.2:provided
[INFO] \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO]    \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4)
```

Full stack trace of Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.ncsts.web.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ncsts/context/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at com.ncsts.web.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2419)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.hibernate.service.StandardServiceInitiators.buildStandardServiceInitiatorList(StandardServiceInitiators.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.service.StandardServiceInitiators.<clinit>(StandardServiceInitiators.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.standardInitiatorList(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1686)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was an overloaded Hibernate class in our code base.